# werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint robotReports' with values ['id']. Did you mean 'reports' instead?

Tags: python, flask

im working on a website with flask so im trying to generate an url to see the reports linked to robots , so i have this route :

```
@app.route("/robotReports/<int:id>")
def reportRobots(id):
    headings = (
         "#",
         "Report Name",
         "Date",
         "Robot",
         "View Logs",
     )
    reports = Report.query.filter_by(robot_id=id).all()
    print(report)
    return render_template("reportsforRobot.html" , reports=reports, headings=headings)
```

and im trying to call it on my HTML page as

`<a href="{{ url_for('robotReports', id=robot.id)}}">`
but when i run it gets
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'robotReports' with values ['id']. Did you mean 'reports' instead?

so , it works when i change it to

`<a href="{{ url_for('reports', id=robot.id)}}">`

because reports its an already working route but the url that i get is

/reports?id=X , and i want reports/X

this is the code for reports

```
@app.route("/reports")
def reports():    
    headings = (
         "#",
         "Report Name",
         "Date",
         "Robot",
         "View Logs",
     )
    return render_template("reports.html",  headings=headings)
```

im really new on this so maybe its a stupid thing, any help is apreciated

Answer (score 0):

So i changed to this

```
@app.route("/robotReports/<int:id>")
def robotReports(id):
    headings = (
         "#",
         "Report Name",
         "Date",
         "Robot",
         "View Logs",
     )
    reports = Report.query.filter_by(robot_id=id).all()
    print(report)
    return render_template("reportsforRobot.html" , reports=reports, headings=headings)
```

and

`<a href="{{url_for('robotReports', id=robot.id)}}">`

and now it works. idk what i did